# How to code an function to print my transactions per second/min

Tags: perl

I have perl v5.8.4, I cannot install any lib/module, I need to use the vanila version.
I have an **perl script that sends HTTP request to an webserver**. I'm trying to code an function to print how many requests I'm sending per sec and per minute to the webserver. The idea is to print once per second and then once per minute.
I was thinking on something like the logic below:

```
# First I get the time I started the script
$time = the time the script started
# Then, for each request I increase $req(for sec) and $reqmin(for minute)
for each request, $req++ and $reqmin++
# When $time hits one sec of load, I will print the number of requests I sent and then I will set back $req to 0, so I can reuse the var for the next second
if $time passed 1 sec, print $req (I think this may give me the TPS)
$req = 0
# Same as above, but for minutes
if $time passed 60sec, print $reqmin
$reqmin = 0
```

The above is not an perl code, but the explanation of what I'm trying to achieve. I'm not trying to get the runtime, control the traffic or do any benchmarking. I'm just trying to get how many requests I'm sending per sec and per min.

I'm not sure if the logic, explained above, is the correct path that I should follow to calculate the TPS(transactions per second) in my code.
The other problem that I have, is that I'm not sure how to calculate the time using perl. Like, I need to know that 1 second has past since the first run to print the *requests per second*, same for 1 minute. I believe I should use perl's time but I'm not sure.

Comment: To the close-vote: I don't think it's unclear, it's just a bit unstructured. Jonathan, please take a moment to [edit] your question and remove typos. Try to get a bit more structure in. So you want to measure how ofter per second you are running some code. Is this for a benchmark, as a debug output, or part of what your program is supposed to do as some sort of status? Do you know how to send the requests? (I think yo do). No need to feel dumb. Your approach is correct, but you need to do some calculations. Some of your pseudo-code is very high-level. We need to drill it down more.

Comment: Hello @simbabque, do you think it's better now? thx

Comment: Yes. Thank you. So have you researched how to do it yourself? I'm not at a computer so I cannot write code now, but it's pretty clear what you need to do. With each iteration you check the time delta, and whenever it increases by a full number you generate output.

Comment: I'm still trying to calc this time delta, still no success. An example would be very helpful!

Comment: You will need Time::HiRes to get micro seconds. Then you need two variables to count. One with the int and one to add time per iteration. After that you check if the micro time variable is higher than the int. If yes, output the count of request and reset it. Then increment the int var.

Comment: @Jonathan And please show us what you are trying. Once you have some sensible code add it.  (It doesn't have to be _correct_ -- that is the question.)  It is much easier to help you out that way, and you generally get far more advice than expected, and you'll find that people are very ready to do so when you post what you have done.

Comment: @zdim I think he's already done some good improvements, even without code. I am at a computer now and will try to hack something quick. But I still don't understand _why_ he needs those numbers.

Comment: @simbabque  I think the numbers would be just to keep track of things. I remember timing response (and averages) to deduce the server's load, so to make my requests more sparse when the load increases.

Comment: @simbabque  Thanks for other info -- I do know that. It's just that sometimes it makes it easier to scan through comments when they're tagged, in situtations when OP responds to a particular user without tagging them. Then we end up with a stream of comments between various people. So I add 'at'.

Comment: Makes sense @zdim. Just checking. :) I've only done rate-limiting in general to make sure we don't do more than we are allowed. But I think I've got an okish implementation in my answer below.

Comment: @simbabque Yes, that's pretty much it I think.  They could also opt for simply timing each request and saving those times, and then later analyze performance, take various avergaes, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've prepared an example for you. Your algorithm is pretty sound. Here's an implementation that does the seconds only. You should be able to go from there.

It uses [Time::HiRes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes), which is included with your old Perl. We need `usleep` only to simulate the requests. The`tv_interval` function gets the delta between two microsecond-times, and `gettimeofday` grabs the current microsecond-time.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw(tv_interval usleep gettimeofday);

$|++; # disable output buffer

my $req_per_second     = 0; # count requests per second
my $sum_towards_second = 0; # sum intervals towards one full second
my $last_timeofday     = [gettimeofday]; # start of each interval

foreach my $i ( 1 .. 10000 ) {
    do_request();

    my $new_timeofday = [gettimeofday]; # end for delta
    my $elapsed = tv_interval( $last_timeofday, $new_timeofday ); # get the delta
    $last_timeofday = $new_timeofday; # new time is old time for the next round
    $sum_towards_second += $elapsed; # add elapsed time to go towards one second
    $req_per_second++; # we did one request within the current second

    # when we arrive at a full second we reset
    if ( $sum_towards_second > 1.0 ) {
        printf "approximately %d req/s\n", $req_per_second;
        $sum_towards_second = $req_per_second = 0;
    }
}

sub do_request {
    usleep rand 1000;    # emulate the request
}
```

This algorithm is close to your idea, and also close to what I sketched out in my comment. In every iteration we start with doing the request, then take the current timestamp. We calculate the delta to the last timestamp and add it to a counter. If that counter reaches `1`, we print the number of requests we've done in that second. Then we can reset both the time counter and the request counter.

The output looks like this.

```
approximately 1785 req/s
approximately 1761 req/s
approximately 1759 req/s
approximately 1699 req/s
approximately 1757 req/s
```

I'll leave counting minutes as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Perhaps add a note that they should make sure not to bombard the server with too much? (With the timing it can even be custom, dynamic. What could be their unstated purpose.)

Comment: No @zdim, I had no unstated purposes. I just wanted to know how to calc the req/s of my application. Using the Time::HiRes did the trick. Thx @simbabque. To add the req/min I added **$sum_towards_minute** and **$req_per_minute**, then I did the same _IF_ but _> 60_ for the new _minute_ vars. To control and test, I changed the _do_request_ to `sub do_request {
    sleep(0.5);
}` of course I had to overwrite the old _sleep_ and use Time::HiRes _sleep_.

Comment: @Jonathan excellent! I'm glad this was helpful and that you actually learned something. :) We don't have a lot of people around here who are interested in learning recently it seems.

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks for the explanation, I see now the comment on that in your question. I thought that you may want to regulate how often you go to the server, thus the timing. (I used to do similar things.) Didn't mean to complain about it -- and doing it just so is fine, of course :)  I time things all the time.